# Avoid double loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8

let say this code

```
  Class A{
       private B;
       private int totalNumberAWithB;
  }      

  enum B {
      type1,type2,type3;
 }
```

If I have

```
  List<A> a;
```

If I have a list of A where they can have or not B instance, I want to have in the totalNumberAWithB the value of all the A that contains a type of B.

Any idea how can I do this efficiently. For now the only idea that cross my mind is create a Map number of B types. And then after finish this loop do again the same loop but this time just set the total values of B types in A. But seems pretty ineficient to me do this double loop.

Any suggestion ideas?

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Do you want to store `totalNumberAWithB` inside class `A` itself? So each instance of A will have the same number?

Comment: I'd say if you're talking about small amounts (in the hundreds) of `A`s and `B`s, you're wasting your time thinking about efficiency. Besides, efficiency is never a case of "it seems".

Comment: I´m afraid is functional requirement. I agree that have the same value for every A is not efficient at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can apply a filter to the stream :

```
a.stream().filter(e -> e.getB() != null).collect(toList());
```

or if just want to count you can just sum :

```
a.stream().filter(e -> e.getB() != null).sum();
```

The filter predicate could be arranged to your needs, or maybe you could even map the elements and then count the aggregate with a reduce operation. *It is a problem that can be solved with a [map/reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)*.